# How to properly use Iterators w/in Python? Python Beginner

Tags: python-3.x, class, iteration

I'm trying to clarify some confusion on the use of `__iter__()` and `__next__()` methods. Here's an example provided from the reading:

Create an iterator that returns numbers, starting with 1, and each sequence will increase by one (returning 1,2,3,4,5 etc.):

```
class MyNumbers:
  def __iter__(self):
    self.a = 1
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    x = self.a
    self.a += 1
    return x

myclass = MyNumbers()
myiter = iter(myclass)

print(next(myiter))
print(next(myiter))
print(next(myiter))
print(next(myiter))
print(next(myiter))
```

I'm trying to learn general patterns here, and am confused by `myiter = iter(myclass)`. First the object `myclass` is created, and belongs to the class `MyNumbers`. This I understand.

Q: But what's going on with the way `myiter` is defined? It's a new object `myiter` set equal to an `iter` function I don't see defined, and including an entire class as a parameter? How does this work exactly? The reading further suggests these iteration methods to be analogous to `__init__` but I don't see the relation. Hows the interpreter exactly go through this code?

Much thank for the time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's see the difference between **iterable** and **iterator**

In our day-to-day programming life, we use for-loop for often.

In below snippet you see that sampleList is iterable.

```
sampleList = [5,8,90,1,2]
for num in sampleList:
    print num
```

How the above statement works: (steps involved in for-loop when it's executing)

- for-loop gets/receives the iterator
- if the iterator has the next item then sets the current index to next available item's index and execute code statement
- if the iterator doesn't have the next item break the loop and come out of it

So now we understand that iterator can take action on the next item.

**But how much information do we know about the iterator() and iterable() functions?**

*Iterator:*
    This contains a method *iter*() and *next*()

Here the iterator itself returns  *iter*(). The primary key element to implement `for num in sampleList`

*Iterable:*
    This contains a method *iter*(). Here this calls sampleList.*iter*() to get an iterator.

Now comes the *next*() definition. difference between the iterable and iterator object is *next*(). *next*() has the two action items on it whenever it called.

1. Update the iterator and point the index to the next item
2. return the current item.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're not "passing a classing as an argument". `myclass` is not a class, it's an instance of the class `MyNumbers`.

In this case, `iter()` calls the `__iter__()` method on thr object you pass, which you defined in the object's class. However, since your `__iter__()` implementation just returns the object itself, the call to `iter()` has no effect here.